# outlook 2016 I have hundreds of folder, having a hard time to search the folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have hundreds of folder, they are organized by client group.
like amazon, TruckerA, ect, ect

I know exactly what I name it but scrolling to 300 folders can be daunting and they cannot alphabetically sorted.

I tried my best to sort it. but it has its flaws.
is there a way I can search by typing the folder name and it will go to it?

thank you

Apologize for the grammatical error and run on sentence.

Comment: If you know the folder name (I think that is what you said), you can use Advanced Search options to search in a specific folder. I have found over (long) time that searching for what I want (content) finds it wherever it is located. That is another way to organize things.  I too have many folders.

Comment: yea, it's mostly for working with few supervisor, I hate scrolling up and down while someone has eyes over my shoulder, I wish I can type the folder name and it just get the folder

Comment: I looked in Advanced Search and in native Outlook, you must browse, but as soon as in that dialogue, you can type the first letter or 2 and browse goes right to that folder.  I have some Z... folders and I can go right there. So the Search options are very powerful in how they can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, please check the steps below:

1. Create a custom Search Folder and specify criteria like below:

[image][image]

2. Click Field > All Mail Fields > In Folder and select is(exactly) as conditions like below. Then we could type the folder name we need in the "Value" box

[image]

3. After those settings, you will get a search folder in your folder list. You can directly search in this folder with Outlook search feature.

[image]